# Reading from ListBox Line by line

Tags: c#

I am creating a program where the user is pressing buttons like move 10 and move 1 to move a robot and when a user presses the button it will add a text in a listbox like "MoveRobot1" so when the user has finished pressing the buttons and presses the Play button, the program should go down the list line by line moving the robot based on the list at an interval of 300ms but I don't understand how to make it read line by line instead of all at once when I press Play.

```
private void BtnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WorkProgress += new WorkProgressHandler(DoWork);
        _counter = 0;

        this.robot.Reset();
        this.MoveRobot(0);
        string query1 = "MoveRobot(1)";
        string query2 = "MoveRobot(10)";
        for (int i = 0; i < MoveBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (MoveBox.Items[i].ToString() == query1)
            {
                this.MoveRobot(1);
                DoWork();

            }
            if (MoveBox.Items[i].ToString() == query2)
            {
                this.MoveRobot(10);
                DoWork();
            }
        }
    }

 private void DoWork()
    {
        _counter++; // increment the counter
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx) in the end of every iteration :

```
for (int i = 0; i < MoveBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (MoveBox.Items[i].ToString() == query1)
    {
        this.MoveRobot(1);
        DoWork();
    }
    if (MoveBox.Items[i].ToString() == query2)
    {
        this.MoveRobot(10);
        DoWork();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(300);
}
```

Comment: That Worked! Thank you so much :)!

Comment: I was wondering, is there a way to make the program read the listbox in order from top to bottom? As it is right now, it is doing all "Move10"s first and then "Move1"s.

Comment: You can try to loop over the list box backwards, something like this: for (int i = MoveBox.Items.Count-1; i>=0; i--)